# NavigationController unable to navigate to destinated ViewController

Tags: swift3

here is my navigation-flow:

VC1 --> VC2 --> V3

at VC1 (which is the Landing Page or main page):

I am use a segue to navigate to VC2 thru a button click

Problem at VC2: 
The NavigationController in VC2 not working, it wont navigate to the targeted UIViewControllers specified.

when in VC2 , I need to navigate to VC3 using navigationalController in code after some conditions met.

here the code for VC2 :

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {

      let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

      if defaults.object(forKey: "SessionToken") == nil {

      let VC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentitfier: "VC3") as! VC3


      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

      self.navigationController?.present(VC, animated: true)


        } else {

                       //-- code for other task--

          }

     }
```

**Update :**

```
 override func viewDidAppear() {

  let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

  if defaults.object(forKey: "SessionToken") == nil {

  let VC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentitfier: "VC3") as! VC3


  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

  self.navigationController?.present(VC, animated: true)


    } else {

                   //-- code for other task--

      }

 }



Override func viewDidLoad() {

  super.viewDidLoad()


 here: I have code to setup calendar functions and others


}
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Why you written `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` ?

Comment: What you want? push to `VC3` or present it on `VC2` ?

Comment: @Amir Khan, I want to navigate to VC3 after checking the condition in VC2. with or without self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) it still wont navigate. VC3 is another ViewController. If condition not met, I want to stay in VC2.

Comment: Can you add the code how you navigate from `VC1` to `VC2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if defaults.object(forKey: "SessionToken") == nil {


        let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC3") as! VC3

        self.present(VC, animated: true) {

        }


    } else {

        //-- code for other task--

    }
}
```

Comment: error Msg: Attempt to present VC3 on <project name> whose view is not in the window hierarchy !  Why this show up?

Comment: @MilkBottle check my updated answer. It was because we were trying to present another `viewcontroller` in `viewDidLoad` method. So you have to move the body from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear` when the VC2 has been fully loaded.

Comment: i move the code into viewDidAppear() BUT it show the VC2 Page first then Navigate to VC3. How not to show VC2 when the condition is true - defaults.object(forKey: "SessionToken") == nil. Base on your solution, viewDidAppear start first, after checking, if it is true, it show immediately navigate to VC3 but somehow it show VC2 before it move to VC3.

Comment: Then @MilkBottle place the condition in VC1 before navigate to VC2. Is it possible? let me know.

Comment: your solution work for THIS condition. I will post any other condition to see if you can use your solution.  why viewWillAppear() cannot work for this condition?

Comment: please check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521957/which-event-to-use-in-landing-pagehome-so-that-it-wont-show-up-when-navigating