# Which event should I use in Landing Page (Home) so that it won't show up when navigating to other VC?

Tags: swift3

I have a view controller named `HomeVC` which acts as a center page to navigate to targeted view controllers based on conditions.

`HomeVC` is the Landing Page or main page.

In `HomeVC`, I have some `UIControl`s like calendars and others.

Problem: The HomeVC shows up a brief second before navigating to VC2 when the condition is met.

Requirements:

How not to show `HomeVC` when condition is met when navigating to another `UIViewController`?

**Update: Requirements**
- not showing the UiControls on HomeVC

Here is the code for HomeVC:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

  super.viewWillAppear(animated)

 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

 if defaults.object(forKey: "SessionToken") == nil {

  let VC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentitfier: "VC2") as! VC2


 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

 self.navigationController?.present(VC, animated: true)


 } else {

       //-- code for other task--

 }

}
```

Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just turn off the dismissing and presenting animation to achieve that.

```
self.navigationController?.present(VC, animated: false)

self.dismiss(animated: false)
```

Comment: I used your suggestion in my code, it wont navigate and the homeVC is showed up when I used navigationController instead of present. Did I miss anything?

Comment: using above statements not working. I have to use self.dismiss(animated:false) and  self.present(VC, animated: false). Even this is OK BUT still see the homeVC in a fraction of a second. How to achieve a very smooth transition so that homeVC wont show up AT ALL? Why NavigationController can not be used in this condition?

Comment: For this to work, I would create a screen that looks just like the launch screen and use that to navigate to other view controllers.

Comment: as my in update requirement above. I think the HomeVC will show anyway. my solution is just make the uicontrol isHidden = true will show nothing on the homeVC so this will look nice.